# nmodbus - Message frame must contain at least 6 bytes of data

Tags: c#, modbus

I am trying to communicate with a PLC over modbus via RS232, but it simply keeps saying that my message from should contain at least 6 bytes of data.
First of all I am sorry for the outlining I always seem to struggle with the code input..., I used the same class for a TCP/IP modbus connection which seems to work quite good, now I am trying to do the same via RTU RS232
I added both of my classes in the edit, thanks in advance I hope someone can help me out.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static ModBusDriver modbusDriver;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1");
        port.BaudRate = 38400;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.ReadTimeout = 600;
        port.WriteTimeout = 600;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;

        modbusDriver = new ModBusDriver(port);
        modbusDriver.connect(1);
        byte slaveAddress = 1;
        modbusDriver.WriteMultipleCoils(slaveAddress, 8193, new bool[6] { false, false, false, false, false, false });
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Modbusdriver.cs

```
using Modbus.Device;
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace CoCoSModBusDriver
{

    // based on nmodbus4: 
    // -https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4
    class ModBusDriver
    {
        public int connected;
        private bool gotClient = false;
        public IModbusSerialMaster modbusConnector;
        public SerialPort serialPort;

        public ModBusDriver(SerialPort port)
        {
            serialPort = port;
            modbusConnector = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);
        }

        public void connect(int retries)
        {

            int retryCounter = 0;
            while (retryCounter < retries || retries == -1)
            {
                try
                {
                    serialPort.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    retryCounter++;
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        }

        public void WriteMultipleCoils(byte slaveAdress, ushort startAdress, bool[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                modbusConnector.WriteMultipleCoils(slaveAdress, startAdress, data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code is problematic? FWIW on the code formatting, 4 spaces to indent.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It goes in the exception after  modbusDriver.WriteMultipleCoils(0,startAdress, data); with the message: Message frame must contain at least 6 bytes of data

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: NModbus4 https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4

Comment: With minor modifications (I don't have the code for what appears to be some form of wrapper class "CoCoSModBusDriver.ModBusDriver") - I needed to open the serial port (5 in my case) - I assume the connect method does that. My slave is at address 1, rather than 0  - but otherwise your code works fine for me. Maybe look in more detail at what the wrapper class is doing. Writing to the wrong slave address causes the code to hang (no response), not opening the port throws a port not open exception.

Comment: @ErwinVorenhout: Note that the exception is referring to the entire of the Modbus message frame - NOT the size of the array you are trying to write.

Comment: Looking through the NModBus4 code - it appears the minimum frame length for the WriteMultipleCoils message is 7 bytes. Does the CoCoSModBusDriver.ModBusDriver class send any other Modbus messages?

Comment: @PaulF I am using the exact same class to be able to communicatie with a IO module without any troubles over TCP/IP , it's only giving me issues over RTU It doesnt send any other messages.

Comment: There are subtle differences between the two protocols - are you sure 0 (first parameter of the WriteMultipleCoils method) is the correct SlaveID for whatever you are connecting to using RTU. In TCP/IP this is the UnitID & is only used for intra-device routing & is typically set to 0 as it is likely to be ignored if message is intended for that device.

Comment: No indeed slaveID 1 should be it, but still given the same message, @paulF I edited my topic with the driver class

Comment: Your edited code is essentially what I came up with & it works on my PC with slave simulator at address 1. So I don't think I can be of further help - all I can suggest is getting the source code & adding it to your project so you can fully debug what is going on.

Comment: PS - your connect method needs a break after serialPort.Open(); otherwise it tries to open the serial port a minimum of two times - the first time it opens the port OK & does not increment retryCounter so the value is still less than retries. The second attempt to open causes an exception, which does cause retryCounter to be incremented & after the 5 second pause the loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the slave address in the request. From the IModbus master interface:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///    Writes a sequence of coils.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="slaveAddress">Address of the device to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="startAddress">Address to begin writing values.</param>
    /// <param name="data">Values to write.</param>
    void WriteMultipleCoils(byte slaveAddress, ushort startAddress, bool[] data);
```

Comment: Check the WriteMultipleCoils(ushort startAdress, bool[] data) method in the example code - that uses a fixed slave address.

Comment: Thanks, completely missed that.

Comment: It looks like there is a "wrapper class" that is missing in the example code "public ModBusDriver(SerialPort port)" being the constructor & it appears to have it's own internal "modbusDriver" field as well as the publicly accessible one.

Comment: A bit dirty indeed, needs some cleaning after a working copy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ModbusSerialMaster class. There is a good example at mesta automations homepage.